# Can Prod and Dev share the same AD? (SP 2016 On-Prem)

Tags: active-directory, migration, staging, azure-active-directory

We are preparing to migrate our client's SP 2016 On-Prem to SP Online.

As our first steps we are planning to:

- Create a Dev environment as a copy of the SP On-Prem (origin), but
  without most of the content.
- Create a Staging environment as a copy of the SP Online
  (destination)

To be honest I don't understand well the role of AD in these different environments.

Can Prod and Dev share the same AD? If yes, is it a good practice?

What about on our destination? How do we set Azure AD for staging?

I've sketched 2 plans:

Plan 1 - Different ADs for Dev and Prod in the origin.

Plan 2 - Share the same AD within the client's vpn.

If you can shed a light on this matter it will be greatly appreciated.

Plan 1
[image: Plan 1]

Plan 2
[image: Plan 2]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to have the same Active Directory user replicated to multiple Azure AD tenants. Because of this, Plan 1 would be more appropriate if you're in a hybrid state, though you will have to maintain separate Active Directory forests.

Comment: Yes we will both ADs separated. Both in the On-Prem Farm and Online Tenants. Thank you so much Trevor.

Comment: You can add users from another Azure AD tenant as a guest in another...it basically works as federation between tenants.  So the account still only exists in one tenant, but can be granted access to another.

Comment: Guests have limitations, however (i.e. they cannot access certain O365 Group resources).

Comment: I haven't run into any personally.  For example, I'm a global administrator on my azure tenant with a guest account.  I dunno what that means for O365, but was assuming this was just being used for SharePoint Online access.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can have multiple SharePoint farms in the same domain.  There is no good or bad practice about it, as there isn't anything domain specific for a SharePoint farm other than the accounts.  It doesn't register any objects in AD.  A good practice would be using separate SQL servers and domain accounts for each farm.

Comment: My concern was loosing some functionality because of SharePoint "not finding" AD users or groups.

Comment: If that is not the case then I might go with Plan 1 in order to have more control over the environment, not depending on the client IT